# Missing context for method declaration pushwoosh xcode

Tags: ios, push, pushwoosh

first sorry for my bad english.
I'm trying to implementate push notification in my Xcode project with pushwoosh. as the docs http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/native-ios-sdk-integration/
i put the code

```
    #import "PushNotificationManager.h"

- (void) onPushAccepted:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification {
    NSLog(@"Push notification received");
}
```

in appDelegate.m but i received this error for the code that i just insert

> Missing context for method declaration

this is the complete file code

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  RistoranteStockholm
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

#import "PushNotificationManager.h"

- (void) onPushAccepted:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification {
    NSLog(@"Push notification received");
}

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, viewController;



- (id)init
{
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

    int cacheSizeMemory = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32MB
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
#else
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
#endif
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate implementation

/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if RistoranteStockholm-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    if (!url) {
        return NO;
    }

    // calls into javascript global function 'handleOpenURL'
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

    return YES;
}

// repost the localnotification using the default NSNotificationCenter so multiple plugins may respond
- (void)            application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification
{
    // re-post ( broadcast )
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVLocalNotification object:notification];
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide what's allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}



@end
```

thanks to everybody

UPDATE ABOUT FILE app delegate.h
I already have this string in app delegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

i need to change in

```
@interface AppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate, PushNotificationDelegate>
```

because if i change it I obtain another error

> cannot find protocol declaration for "PushNotificationDelegate"

i change appdelegate.h from this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{}

// invoke string is passed to your app on launch, this is only valid if you
// edit RistoranteStockholm-Info.plist to add a protocol
// a simple tutorial can be found here :
// http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;

@end
```

to this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>


@interface AppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate, PushNotificationDelegate>{}

// invoke string is passed to your app on launch, this is only valid if you
// edit RistoranteStockholm-Info.plist to add a protocol
// a simple tutorial can be found here :
// http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;

@end
```

thanks

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Delegate method should be below your `@implementation AppDelegate` line

```
@implementation AppDelegate

// Other code

- (void) onPushAccepted:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification {
    NSLog(@"Push notification received");
}

@end
```

Don't forget to conform your `AppDelegate` with `PushNotificationDelegate` in `AppDelegate.h` file

```
#import "PushNotificationManager.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, PushNotificationDelegate>
```

Comment: I missed inheriting from NSObject, please do that too

Comment: Have you imported PushNotificationManager.h ?